# How define non-continious function in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm searching how to define an expression in sympy like
f(x)=x for x<0 and x**2+2 for x>0
i tried whithout success similar comprehension list
thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is known as a piecewise function:

```
In [1]: p = Piecewise((x, x<0), (x**2 + 2, x>0))                                                                                               

In [2]: p                                                                                                                                      
Out[2]: 
⎧  x     for x < 0
⎪                 
⎨ 2               
⎪x  + 2  for x > 0
⎩
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sympy-functions-elementary-piecewise

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You're looking for a piecewise function. Here's a quick snippet to get you up to speed.

```
from sympy import Piecewise # import the Piecewise function
p = Piecewise((x, x < 0), (x**2+2, x > 0)) # the general form is: Piecewise((branch, condition), (branch, condition), ...)
p # display the equation
```

This is the output:

[image]